# Installation of an OS within the USB/DVD

Tags: usb

Is it possible to run an OS by installing an OS within the USB/DVD like running an OS in pc/laptop ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a Persistent USB install of Elementary.

I googled around and found [this discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/5i3oym/creating_a_persistent_live_usb_of_elementary_os/) and [this one on StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255860/how-to-make-elementary-os-persistent).

The TL;DR is that it isn't as straightforward as clicking a few buttons, but it can be done with minimal effort. You'll need a big-ish USB drive too.